# Regex for a formatted convention

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a string conforms to a particular format. An example of the correctly written string is **`12/KMY(Naing)056503`**. The first part is a number which is either one digit or two digit but is less than or equal to 15. This is followed by a stroke. The second part is a three letter code. The next part **`(Naing)`** has to be exactly spelled this way for all texts written in this format. The last part is a six digit number. Can a regex be written to check if the input conforms to this pattern?

Comment: @AlexShesterov is he not allowed to ask or what are you intending to express with your comment?

Comment: @Valinho, of course he's allowed to ask, where did you read it in my comment? 
I just stated the fact. 
But also please note that the question doesn't include any code; it's one of typical "do some work for me" questions, which are in fact not welcome on this site (see votes) (by the way, I didn't downvote it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(1[0-5]|[0-9])/[A-Z]{3}\(Naing\)[0-9]{6}
```

I've tested it against your example at http://regexpal.com/ and it seems to work fine.

Comment: If you're using it in Java, you'll need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: (the startup digits) one digit is also acceptable, for example 9 should be acceptable.

Comment: You should also provide working Java code since you are spoon-feeding.

Comment: The expression above does accept one digit (I assume you mean at the start)?

Comment: @JamesBaker I think it supposedly refers to any number below 15

Comment: @nafas - The expression above will accept any number beginning from 0 to 15 (inclusive).

Comment: @JamesBaker dude ur right, I'm very sorry I didn't see or symbol. I need to change my glasses hehe